# Ionic Php Sql XmlRpc

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

I have an problem with my hybrid mobile app developed with ionic frameworks

My app use the http post with PHP/SQL server and i on localhost php all is Ok but on my server i have Access problem same to  XMLHttpRequest: Erreur réseau 0x80070005

Here some parts of my angular code

```
$http.post("http://www.worldinnov.com/drive-r/api/"+"getTableData",     
{'table':'courses_vtc','where':'uid','value':$scope.courseUID}).then(function(result){
        if(result && result.data){
          if(result.data[0].paiement_client == "A PAYER AU CHAUFFEUR"){
            $http.post("http://www.worldinnov.com/drive-r/api/"+"validePaiement",{uid:$scope.courseUID}).then(function(result){
                 if(result && result.data){
                   if(result.data.status=="success"){
                      sharedUtils.showAlert("PAIEMENT ACCEPTE", "Le paiement a été encaissé");
                   }
                 }
            });
          } else{
             sharedUtils.showAlert("ERREUR", "Le paiement à dejà été effectué");
          }
        }

     });
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: i have a new error : Access-Control-Allow-Origin i don't how resolved my problem thanks for your help